# How can I cope with different return types without templating a class so as to preserve API interface

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, return-type

I'm doing some computation on either a CPU or GPU. The GPU doesn't have a double (64 bit) type, so I've different return types based on what I run the calculation on. I've got the following working using templates,

```
#include <iostream>

// GPU.h
struct GPU {
    using Ret = float;
    Ret vals[5];
    void calc() { vals[0] = 0.0f; vals[1] = 1.0f; } // Do some calculation.
    Ret* res() { return vals; }  // Return pointer to result from calc().
};

// CPU.h
struct CPU {
   using Ret = double;
   Ret vals[5];
   void calc() { vals[0] = 1.0; vals[1] = 2.0; } // Do some calculation.
   Ret* res() { return vals; }  // Return result from calc().
};

// Process.h
template<class T>
struct Process {
    using Ret = typename T::Ret;
    void calc() { t.calc(); }
    Ret* res() { return t.res(); }

    T t;
};

int main() {
    Process<CPU> p;
    p.calc();
    auto res = p.res();
    std::cout << (res[0] + res[1]) << '\n';
}
```

My problem is that if I try and put a Process member into a class I need to template that class. The following was fine when I was using just CPU, as I knew that Ret would be double. Adding GPU means I need to go from,

```
struct X {
    Process p;
};
```

to

```
template<class Impl>
struct X {
    Process<Impl> p;
};
```

I'd really like not to change Process, as the choice of CPU/GPU is an implementation detail and the user of Process shouldn't have to know about it, or choose.

I tried using an example I saw Sean Parent talk about at Going Native 2013, the object_t type near the end of the following file,

https://github.com/boostcon/cppnow_presentations_2012/blob/master/fri/value_semantics/value_semantics.cpp

I can get this working for calc(), as it returns void. But it doesn't work for res(), as the return type varies. Additionally, I can't specify a templated virtual function in concept_t.

```
template<class R>
virtual R res() = 0;
```

I've had a quick go at trying to access Ret in CPU and GPU, but I can't work out how to do it as part of the function declaration in concept_t.

My final thought, that i've not tried yet, is to make CPU and GPU singletons. Then I would only use them in Process.cpp. I won't need to store a Process member variable, and Process.h doesn't need to know about CPU and GPU, preserving its interface.

Anyone got any ideas/recommendations as I can't see a way around this that is neat and preserves the existing interfaces.

Comment: The only difference is the return type?  And I assume you're using a different compiler/build to produce different executables for each platform?  I would use a typedef to define the return type and an #ifdef to properly define which one to to use for each build.

Comment: I'm using OpenCL, that's how I can run the same code on a CPU or GPU. It abstracts the actual device differences for me.

I'd like to be have some flexibility at run-time. OpenCL allows me to look at the capabilities of the CPU/GPU. Then i'd like to choose which one to run on. Hence my idea of using singletons.

Comment: I can think of various solutions but you need to describe the result and what you're going to do with it in more detail.

Comment: The result will be a pointer to a 2d array of values. I'm processing images and generating cumulative sums of the values of the rows and columns. What i'm calculating is a [Summed Area Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed_area_table).

Once processed, you can find the average of a rectangular section of the image by using the 4 corner values in your calculated results. Hence my returning a pointer to all the values. I then calculated 1d indexes of the 4 corners and get the values for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just store the result you've got from a device in a double? `Process` is some kind of facade that encapsulates computation and conversion of the result. Users of `Process` don't care about devices and their supported floating point types. They are using `double`.

```
template<class Device>
struct Process {
    void calc() { t.calc(); }
    double res() { 
        // Device::res returns something you can assign to a double
        return t.res(); 
    }

    Device device;
};
```

**Edit:**
If the return value is not just a single value but a collection of doubles you might want to write a wrapper around the device results.

```
struct Process {
    void calc();
    const Result& res();
};

struct Result {
    virtual ~Result() = default;
    virtual double operator[](size_t n) const = 0;
};
```

This could be implemented for your GPU results for example like

```
struct GPUResult {
    GPUResult(float* r) : results{ r } {}

    virtual double operator[](size_t n) const {
        return results[n];
    }
    float* results;
};
```

Comment: I simplified a bit too much, the types would actually be pointers. One to float* and the other to double*.

Comment: @PhilWright What's the point in using a pointer to a floating point number which represents a result? Do you want the caller of `res()` to modify the value?

Comment: The result isn't a single value. Sorry if I confused you by suggesting this in my example code.

No, in this case I don't want to modify the memory. But in other instances I might.

If the computation is done on the GPU, the memory used will be somewhere in GPU-accessible memory. Rather than copy it back to CPU memory, you can obtain a pointer to the memory. Hence the non-const  pointer, this is what the OpenCL API returns.

[link](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/)

Comment: @PhilWright I think it doesn't matter if it's a single value or an array. Provide a wrapper that hides the detail of result types. I edit my post (there's probably a better solution but you see the concept).